# Random Forest Dataset Variability

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, dataset

I am going to implement a Random Forest Regressor and remember reading somewhere, that the datasets for learning should be as diferent as possible for a good pretiction. (Unfortunately I can not find that source text anymore, Neither after a search in the web I can not find support for this assumption) Therefore I would run a L1-Norm distance measure on my feature matrix for all datasets and dismiss those with a too low value.

Resulting in these Questions:

- Can anyone support the assumption of using high variability between the          datasets?
- If yes, is there a suggestion on a more suitable way than the L1-Norm?
- Suggestions for python implementation, better than numpy's linalg norm?

**EDIT:**

In the case of the trainingset below I would only dismiss v1 or v4. 
V marks a dataset (=5 counts) holding 8 features each.

[image: Training Data v1-5 Datasets, with 8 features and a 1D target.]

Comment: I do not fully understand the question. Your dataset should in the best case be a representative sample of the real use case. The only case in which I would want to dismiss specific datapoints is outliers.

Comment: You aren't looking to extrapolate.  You want both the test and train sets to be representative.  You want them to be non-identical, so you can measure and minimize interpolation error.  If you use one to train, you can't (easily) use it to test performance and get a clean estimate how well the learner "generalizes".  A well trained system handles new data without getting lost in the weeds.  This is why you split it.  There is also the point that many rows are better than few.  If you have to split data, make sure both traverse domain adequately.

Comment: @EngrStudent I understand the concept of splitting the training and testing sets. What I am acutally asking is, if I need to get rid of similar datasets (or in this case too close ones) in my training set?

Comment: The goal is to have realistic enough data in the training, validation, and test.  If you use uniform random sampling when doing the splitting, then don't throw away "similar" in your training.  In the limit of infinite samples, you would train on all possible inputs, validate, and test.  You would know your exact performance.  In the reality of less than infinite samples, as long as you are sampling fairly, you should still get a good estimate.  I do NOT know any code or practitioner in the field who says "I can't have the same data value in both training and validation"

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess what you were asking I would say that you claim to have read in some source that random forest does not perform optimally on a dataset which shows symptoms of multicollinearity. You have built a similarity matrix using Manhattan distance in order to filter out features which are "too close", and you are wondering whether this is the best method to get rid of those highly correlated variables. Am I right so far?

First things first: I don't know what you've read and where but there is nothing in the Random Forest algorithm (nor simple CART) which can theoretically have its performance affected by highly correlated features. In practice, though, you may need to fine tune hyperparameters (such as the number of trees in the forest) to make up for the added variance that highly correlated variable may introduce to the model in the form of noise. If you keep a large number of trees, this should not be an issue.

Secondly, if you really need to remove highly correlated variables then your approach of using the L1-norm is completely wrong as it does not really measure correlation to begin with. In order to do this right you may either:

- perform univariate linear regression between all features to assess the statistical significance of their pairwise correlations
- apply a multivariate method for dimensionality reduction such as principal component analysis.

I would go for the second method.

Comment: not exactly. I do not want to get rid of too close features but rather on too close datasets. One datasets consists of some feature let us say 8. And my training data consists of 1mil+ such datasets. Now I do L1 distance on the datasets, pairwise. And if the similarity is too high, equals a small L1-Norm, I dismiss this dataset. Multicollinearity is not the correct word I think. Since I would not dismiss a one of the vectors if:V1 = [1 2 3] and V2 = [2 4 6] since L1 norm is high. But I would dismiss: V1 =[1 2 3] and V2 = [1.1 2.1 3.1] for example.